# Does the integral $\int_a^b f(t) dt$ exist if $f(t)$ is defined on $[a, b)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

In discrete sum, I can define a recursive function as

$$s(k) = \sum_{i=k-d}^{k-1} s(i)$$

where $d>0$ is a constant. Obviously, if I know the values of $s(k)$ for $k \in \{-d, -d+1, \dots, -1\}$, I can calculate all the values of $s(k)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}^ {\geq 0}$.

My question is does this also holds for integration? Does the function

$$s(t) = \int_{t-d}^{t} s(\tau) d\tau$$

is also recursive in the above sense when I know $s(t)$ at $t \in [-d, 0)$.

To put in another way, does the integral  $\int_a^b f(t) dt$ exist if $f(t)$ is defined on $[a, b)$?

**Edit:** We can suppose $f(t)$ is a "sufficiently nice" function. My only concern is that is the integral legal when $f(b)$ is undefined.

**Edit:** To clarify, assuming $s(t)$ for $t \in [-d,0)$ is integrable, is the function
$$s(t) = \int_{t-d}^{t} s(\tau) d\tau$$
well-defined?

Comment: No. Take $[0,1)$ and $1/(1-x)$.

Comment: Well, suppose $f(t)$ is bounded for all $t$. I should ask as if it is legal may be?

Comment: The value at the single point $b$ is never an issue.  Whether the integral exists depends on that "sufficiently nice".

Comment: @RobertIsrael So my recursive $s(t)$ function is well-defined? (Of course assuming $s(t)$ for $t \in [-d,0)$ is sufficiently nice.)

Comment: This is a different issue.  But yes: if $s(t)$ is, let's say, bounded and continuous on $[-d,0)$, then on $[0,d)$ we have $$s(t) = e^t \left(\int_{-d}^0 s(u-d)\; du - \int_0^t e^{-u} s(u-d)\; du\right)$$ and we continue inductively.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I didn't quite understand how you came up with this result. Could you explain a little? Also, the first integral doesn't seem right as we need to know $s(-2d)$ to $s(-d)$.

Comment: Sorry, that first integral should have been $\int_{-d}^0 s(u)\; du$.  This comes from solving the differential equation $s'(t) = s(t) - s(t-d)$ on $[0,d)$ (treating $s(t-d)$ as known) with $s(0) = \int_{-d}^0 s(u)\; du$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I got it, thanks. Do you want to post these comments as an answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 0):

You need your function $f$ to be integrable on $[a,b)$ for whatever version of "integral" you are using (probably Riemann, maybe Lebesgue).